# My Grunt Modules are enormous. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I've started using NodeJS and Grunt to do things like run LESS, Concat JS library files and Uglify them, etc.  I have a total of only 5 modules installed:  less, concat, watch, copy, and uglify.

My node_modules directory contains a whopping 3,500 files!

I am using this setup in 4 related projects in my SVN repository. Since Grunt doesn't support any kind of "global" installation, I have to install these modules separately for every project.

That's added 14,000 files to my repository, and and added a very, very large amount of time to me check-out process.

I can't imagine that everyone using Grunt is quietly ignoring and tolerating this kind of repository bloat, but I can't see how to reduce the module size.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong??  How do I get the functionality of less, concat, watch, copy, and uglify, but without the ridiculous file count that I'm seeing today?

Comment: I never check in `node_modules/` and just run `npm install` after a checkout.

Comment: may be install them in a single folder then inside `node_modules/` create symbolic links for each of them?

Answer (score 0):

i dont know of a way to get the functionality without having the files on disk.

but the usual solution to avoid bloating your repo is to rely on `npm install` to get all those files. add `node_modules/` and maybe `bower_components/` to your `.gitignore` to make sure you dont commit them by accident.

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-contrib-copy
git add package.json; git commit -m 'Add grunt copy dep'; git push
cd ~
git checkout https://github.com/myName/myGruntProject; cd myGruntProject
npm install
grunt
```